# An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred

Tags: arcobjects, c#

I am trying to learn Arcobject with C# through a book named "begining arcgis desktop using dotnet" , in this book an example is given to use geoprocesisng tool to be used through arcobject.

below in the code

```
IMxDocument mxdoc = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
IMap map = mxdoc.FocusMap;
if (map.Layer[0] == null)
{ return; }
ILayer layer = map.Layer[0];
IDataset dataset = layer as IDataset;
IGeoProcessor2 gp = new GeoProcessorClass();
gp.AddOutputsToMap = true;
gp.OverwriteOutput = true;
//syntax of the tool from tool's reference page
//MultipleRingBuffer_analysis (Input_Features, Output_Feature_class,     Distances,
//{Buffer_Unit}, {Field_Name}, {Dissolve_Option}, {Outside_Polygons_Only})
IVariantArray parameters = new VarArrayClass();
//Input_Features
parameters.Add(layer);
//Output_Feature_class
parameters.Add(dataset.BrowseName + "MRB");
//you have to use ; to separate the distances (multivalue)
parameters.Add("10;50;100");
//{Buffer_Unit}
parameters.Add("kilometers");
//{Field_Name}
parameters.Add("");
//{Dissolve_Option}
parameters.Add("ALL");
gp.Execute("MultipleRingBuffer_analysis", parameters, null);
object severity = null;
MessageBox.Show(gp.GetMessages(ref severity));
```

it throws an error of "An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in GeoprocessingProject.dll"

i am new to dot net. can some body help to resolve this error ?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is your output. If you look at the [help](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISDESKTOP/10.0/HELP/index.html#//00080000001p000000) for this tool the syntax section clearly states the output is a FEATURECLASS.

You are providing a string which is the browse name + "MRB", so if your dataset you are buffering was called city then the output name is cityMRB. As you can see from my example your string does not say *where* to create this dataset. You would need to set the output workspace or provide a full path. Based upon the name I assume it is a geodatabase featureclass so what you should be supplying is a full path such as "C:\temp\mygeo.mdb\cityMRB"

I suspect the error is occurring because of that and it's defaulting to some location which is not creating a valid output FEATURECLASS name?